# array sort by keys.

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a following array,

```
$versions = array
(
    '0.9.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/0.9.md5',
    '1.0.0.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.0.md5',
    '1.0.1.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.1.md5',
    '1.0.2.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.2.md5',
    '1.0.3.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.3.md5',
    '1.0.9.1.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.1.md5',
    '1.0.9.10.1.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.10.1.md5',
    '1.0.9.10.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.10.md5',
    '1.1.3.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.1.3.md5',
    '1.0.9.2.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.2.md5',
    '1.0.9.3.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.3.md5',
    '1.0.9.8.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.8.md5',
    '1.0.9.9.1.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.9.1.md5',
    '1.0.9.9.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.9.md5',
    '1.0.9.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.md5',
    '1.1.0.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.1.0.md5',
    '1.1.1.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.1.1.md5',
    '1.1.2.md5' => '/var/www/md5_test/1.1.2.md5',
);
```

In this array i want to sort this by keys. I have searched,

Ex: It should order like:  `1.0.9.md5, 1.0.9.1.md5,.. , 1.0.9.10.md5, 1.0.9.10.1.md5`

I have tried

`ksort($versions);`

But i could't get exactly what i want.

Comment: Explain *float* in this context?

Comment: Post your attempts what you have tried

Comment: Have you tried ksort?

Comment: yep @RobFoley but i did't get the expected result

Comment: so what do you expect? ksort make this array sorted by key in alphabetical order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If these are version numbers, and you need to sort by the version so that `1.0.9.2.md5` comes before `1.0.9.10.1.md5` then you need a custom sort based on semantic versioning:

```
uksort($versions, 'version_compare');
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/erlIVE)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ".md5" -> ksort() -> add the ".md5" again.

```
foreach($versions as $key => $value) {

    $newKey         = str_replace(".md5", "", $key);
    $new[$newKey]   = $value;

}

ksort($new);

foreach($new as $key => $value) {

    $newKey         = $key . ".md5";
    $result[$newKey]= $value;

}

print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0.9.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/0.9.md5
    [1.0.0.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.0.md5
    [1.0.1.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.1.md5
    [1.0.2.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.2.md5
    [1.0.3.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.3.md5
    [1.0.9.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.md5
    [1.0.9.1.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.1.md5
    [1.0.9.10.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.10.md5
    [1.0.9.10.1.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.10.1.md5
    [1.0.9.2.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.2.md5
    [1.0.9.3.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.3.md5
    [1.0.9.8.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.8.md5
    [1.0.9.9.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.9.md5
    [1.0.9.9.1.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.0.9.9.1.md5
    [1.1.0.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.1.0.md5
    [1.1.1.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.1.1.md5
    [1.1.2.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.1.2.md5
    [1.1.3.md5] => /var/www/md5_test/1.1.3.md5
)
```

Comment: why? ksort do same thing with or without .md5 suffix

Comment: Are you sure? Not according to my tests.